# Mutual TLS for webhook, using nginx

Tags: nginx, docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's eSignature API. Rails app, server is nginx. I'm trying to get Mutual TLS working, with no luck so far. I used the instructions [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/mutual-tls/mutual-tls-nginx/).

I'm currently in DocuSign's sandbox - is there any reason Mutual TLS wouldn't work in the sandbox? I'm not seeing $ssl_client_fingerprint or $ssl_client_s_dn in my access_log.

Edit: I'm not getting any errors from nginx. Webhooks are working, I just don't see the client fingerprint, or $ssl_client_s_dn in my nginx logs. My lone question is: does mutual TLS with nginx work when webhook POSTs come from DocuSign's sandbox?

Edit 2: I figured out my issue. The nginx configuration was fine. I didn't have verify_ssl_host set to true when creating the DocuSign API client.

```
    configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
    configuration.host = base_path
    configuration.verify_ssl_host = true # I was missing this
    api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new(configuration)
```

Comment: I'm sorry Tim but we need a lot more information to help you:
1. Your code.
2. "No luck" is probably an error message? can you provide the error you are getting.
3. Can you do Connect without Mutual TLS? start with a simple scenario that is not as secure as needed, just to ensure you get the basics in place.

Comment: I have a simple question really: does mutual TLS work in DocuSign's sandbox? I need to rule that out. No luck means mutual TLS isn't working. I don't need help getting webhooks working. Connect works. Simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Mutual TLS can work in the Developer Environment (also known as "Sandbox" or demo).

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-mutual-tls-stuff-know has more information about it.

If you need help with that - please provide more information about your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using v2.0.0 of the docusign_esign ruby gem. I'm using eventNotification settings in the envelope, like this:

      DocuSign_eSign::EventNotification.new(
        :includeDocuments => true,
        :requireAcknowledgment =>true,
        :loggingEnabled => true,
        :signMessageWithX509Cert => true,
        :url => WEBHOOK_URL,
        :envelopeEvents => envelope_events
      )

Comment: Sorry I'm running out of space in the comment.

Comment: I have this in my http block (but with my own cert)


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/listener.worldwidecorp.us/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/listener.worldwidecorp.us/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_client_certificate /home/ubuntu/connect_root.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on; # Require Mutual TLS
    ssl_verify_depth 10; # Enable verification of the client’s certificate```
  
I'm using the DigiCert Global Root G2 certificate for ssl_client_certificate. Is there anything I need to do to initiate the TLS handshake?

Comment: you can update the original question instead of writing comments...